# iPhone: Newbie memory management question

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am just getting started with cocoa. So please excuse the silly question, but I can't quite wrap my head around some aspects of memory management yet.

In the interface of my class I am declaring an object as `CEMyObjectclass *myObject;`. I do not alloc or init the obect in the classe's init menthod. But I do have a method that calls `myObject = [[CEMyObjectclass alloc] initWithImage:someImage];`. Will that eventually run out of memory or does `myObject` just get overwritten by a new instance every time that method is called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should eventually run out.

Remember that `myObject` is just a pointer to a block of memory. The pointer `myObject` will be pointing to the newly allocated object, and you'll have no reference to the old one. Therefore, you won't be able to release its memory (but the object will still be around).

In general, if you `alloc` something (or `retain` it), you are responsible for matching this message with a `release` somewhere later.

Comment: The garbage collector won't clean this up?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no garbage collector on the iPhone.

Comment: When an app exits entirely... is 'leaked memory' still leaked?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I'd say generally (in practically all cases) no. The OS will clean up after your app once it exits -- it's part of its responsibility to keep the system stable (even in the face of "leaking" apps).